# массивы в языке С

Tags: c, массивы

*Создать массив из 10 элементов.Написать программу, которая добавляет между двумя соседними
элементами целочисленного массива их среднее арифметическое, если оно
больше заданного значения x.*

Помогите пж с вот этой задачей, я не до конца понимаю что мне делать с массивом. Я написал решение, но оно неправильно.

```
int main()
{
    int x = 0, b;
    int A[10] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

    printf("input your number: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &x);
    for (int i = 1; i < 9; ++i)

    {
        b = (A[i - 1] + A[i]) / 2;

        if (x < b)
        {
            A[i + 1] = A[i];
            A[i] = b;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; ++i)
    {
        printf("A[%d]= ", i);
        printf("%d ", A[i]);
    }
}
```

То есть когда я суммирую два соседних элемента, то переношу последнее число на место другого. Если же мне именно между ними это среднее арифметическое добавлять, то будет переполнение массива. Куда мне вообще девать последние  элементы массива? Смысл от них, если их место все равно займут совершенно другие цифры.

Comment: Надо создать новый массив, размером побольше, и расставлять данные в нем.

Comment: новый массив из 19 элементов?

Comment: @rendy, да. Первый массив из 10 элементов это **исходные данные**, а второй это **результат** их обработки.

Comment: Можно не создавать новый массив, если вам старые данные не нужны, а записать поверх них средние арифметические. Либо изначально создать массив размера 19, но заполнить только 10 первых элементов

Answer (score 1):

Надо сделать новый динамический массив с 19 элементами. Потом прогнать ваш алгортим. А потом уменьшить количество элементов (можно счётчиком считать, сколько всего надо) с помощью realloc.

Comment: Счетчик (количество заполненных элементов массива) понадобится в любом случае